# how using parameter value to call function?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to use passed parameter to call function in javascript.

eg:

```
var Animal = (function(){
    function Animal(type){
        this.type(); eg this.snake(); if the parameter type is "snake"
    }
    return Animal;
})();

var animal = new Animal("snake");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript object properties act like [associative arrays](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html) so `this.a == this['a']`

```
   var Animal = (function(){
        function Animal(type){
            this[type](); //eg this.snake(); if the parameter type is "snake"
        }
        return Animal;
    })();
```

Comment: They do not act like arrays.

Comment: @Starx is right, functions are not arrays, they're objects! And objects **have** *dot notation* and *bracket notation*.

Comment: i said they act like associative arrays , obviously objects are not arrays,, act like

Comment: Associative array are also arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference it like an ***array***. In your case it would be `this[type]`

```
function Animal(type){
    this[type]();
}
```

**Additionally,** if you do not know the object or if the variable is global, then you can use `window` like in the same context. For example

```
var apple = 'tasty';
var fruit = 'apple';
console.log(window[fruit]); // Will give `tasty` as output
```